# R string match between two dataframe columns

Tags: r, string

I am trying to extract texts based on a match in a character column of a dataframe with a column of another dataframe. Here is an example of reproducible dataframes.

```r
productlist <- data.frame(prod_tg=c('Milk', 'Soybean', 'Pig meat'), 
                          nomencl=c('milk|SMP|dairy|MK', 'Soybean|Soyabean', 'Pigmeat|PK|Pork|pigmeat') )

tctdf <- data.frame(policy_label=c('Market Milk', 'dairy products', 'OCHA - MK', 'pig meat', 'Soybeans'))
```

I would like to match the strings case insensitive. In the productlist, I have included all entries in nomencl column by using '|' so that any match of these will go specific entry of prod_tg such as Milk, Pig meat, Soybean.

my expected dataframe would look like as:

```r
finaldf = data.frame(policy_label=c('Market Milk', 'dairy products', 'OCHA - MK', 'pig meat', 'Soybeans'), prod_match=c('milk', 'dairy', 'MK','pig', 'Soybean'), product_tag=c('Milk', 'Milk', 'Milk', 'Pig meat', 'Soybean'))
```

I have been thinking of `grepl` function in base R but open to any other function. Grateful for your suggestions.

Comment: Typo, `<=`, I'm guessing you mean `=` or `<-`. Please post code you've actually tried and used, it is frustrating trying to parse through simple copy/paste errors to weed out actual typos in your code.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Sorry for the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using `stringr::str_extract`

```
library(stringr)

cbind(tctdf,t(sapply(tctdf$policy_label, function(x) {
  v <- str_extract(x, regex(productlist$nomencl, ignore_case = TRUE))
  c(prod_match = toString(na.omit(v)), 
    product_tag = toString(productlist$prod_tg[!is.na(v)]))
}))) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)

#    policy_label prod_match product_tag
#1    Market Milk       Milk        Milk
#2 dairy products      dairy        Milk
#3      OCHA - MK         MK        Milk
#4        pigmeat    pigmeat    Pig meat
#5       Soybeans    Soybean     Soybean
```

**data**

Changed `<=` to `<-` for `tctdf` and replaced `'pig meat'` to `'pigmeat'` so that it actually matches with `productlist`.

```
tctdf <- data.frame(policy_label=c('Market Milk', 'dairy products', 
                                   'OCHA - MK', 'pigmeat', 'Soybeans'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. I am not sure what the last part of your code '|> `rownames<-`(NULL)' means. I ignored this part and the code seem works fine.

Comment: Yes, that would work fine as well. That part of code is removing rownames from the output.

Comment: One thing I faced later on when using my original large dataframe was that the code extracted some unneeded strings. For example, I wanted to find 'rice' from the dataframe, and if the column has string 'price' it extracted rice even though it is not the expected result. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can add word boundary to avoid it. Change `v <- str_extract(x, regex(productlist$nomencl, ignore_case = TRUE))` to `v <- str_extract(x, regex(sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', productlist$nomencl), ignore_case = TRUE))` @AbdullahMamun